# Not able to access Context.BAKUP_SERVICE in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have recently started working with Android Studio to understand backup and restore part. I have been trying to develop an application in which I am facing this Error.

```
mBackupManager = IBackupManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager
                .getService(Context.BACKUP_SERVICE));
```

I am not able to find the `Context.BACKUP_SERVICE`. It is defined with `@hide` in `Context.java`.  Is there any way to access it? please, help me.

Comment: Why are you not using `BackupManager`? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupManager

Comment: considered using it  but couldn't find any method that is used for backingup a particular package . After long research ,  I found a method from IBackupmanager but cant use it unless i get access to this .

Comment: "considered using it but couldn't find any method that is used for backingup a particular package" -- backing up apps is the OS's job. You, in your own app, merely specify what should be backed up (and, to a lesser extent, when it should get backed up).